# BASH:Check if variable value begins with [

Tags: bash

I am using `[[ $each_word == [* ]]` right now. 
It doesn't cause an error, but I am not sure if it is safe.
Also does this cover all cases for words that begin with '['

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the parser treats `[` literally instead of as the start of a bracket expression because the bracket expression ends prematurely. To be safe, I would quote it to make explicit that you want a literal `[`:

```
[[ $each_word == "["* ]]
```